# Why is my search button below my search bar

Tags: html, css

I am making a search bar for an idea of mine and I'm still very new to CSS. 
My search button is below my text bar and my on hover button and I can't figure out the solution or find the reason why!

I have tried changing the margins, padding, and top/bottom percentages but to no avail

HTML

```html
        <div class="search-box">
            <div class="location">
                <input name="location" type="text" 
                                       placeholder="location"/>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdwn">
                <button class="dropbtn">dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdwn-content">
                    <img src="../Media/sunny.png" alt="Sunny"                                                          
                                                  width="50" height="50">
                    <img src="../Media/partly_cloudy.png" 
                     alt="partly_cloudy" width="50"height="50">
                <img src="../Media/rain_s_cloudy.png" alt="rain_s_cloudy" 
                                                   width="50"height="50"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbtn">
                <button type="button">Search</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.search-box
{
    width: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
}
.location input
{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}

.dropdwn
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.searchbtn button
{
    float: right;

}
.dropdwn-content
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I am expecting my searchbtn to be top right of the box instead of the bottom right

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `display: inline-block`, the whitespace matters. This can mess up `%`-based layouts and indentation a bit (see below).

The other issue I see is with your rules around setting `input` width, as this will affect the child element instead -- telling it to fill 50% of `.location` instead of `.search-box`.

I've simplified your code to highlight these changes, and added some %'s so that the input and buttons will stretch (or shrink) to fill their parents, who will in turn fill `.search-box`. A simple `float: right` on the `.searchbtn` element now sends it to the right, without a new line.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-box
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 60%;
}

.search-box > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.search-box button, input {
  width: 100%;
}

.location {
  width: 50%;
}


.searchbtn {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">

  <div class="location">
  <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="location"/>
  </div><div class="dropdwn">
  <button class="dropbtn">dropdown</button>
  </div><div class="searchbtn">
  <button type="button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can see this is not quite what you're after. Hang on a sec.